# How to create data view models in Loopback?

Tags: mysql, node.js, loopbackjs

Basically what the title asks. I'm wondering if it's possible to create a a custom view model in Loopback that is datasource ignorant?

My current process has been to create a view in MySQL, and then build a model in Loopback that overlays the view, but I recently realized that if we decide to migrate to a different back end, or change the datasource somehow, we'd have to figure out how to recreate the view.

Google searches on this have revealed bupkis, so I figured I'd throw it out here to see if anyone has knowledge on the topic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ultimately, are looking for some cache system ?

Comment: Ultimately I'm looking to generate some pretty complex reports that pull information from across a number of different models. I can generate custom queries every time, but I've found that the access is way faster if I create a view in MySQL. I'm curious if it's possible to abstract the view generation to Loopback to allow for better migration/easier maintainability in the future

Answer (score 0):

Using views in Loopback works well. Just treat the view as if it were a table and Loopback will treat it the same way. In fact you can actually perform some write operations against the view if you want to. Assuming you have already created the view in SQL here's a snippet to create end-points from an existing table or view in Loopback:

```
/**
 * Creates a REST endpoint using the persistedModel.
 * @function createPersistedModelApi
 */
function createPersistedModelApi(app, dataSourceName: string, tablename: string, callback) {

    let eventInfo: Type.Event
    let ds = app.datasources[dataSourceName];

    ds.discoverSchema(tablename, null, function(err, schema) {

        if (!err) {

            // Set the key field.                
            schema.properties.rowid.id = true;

            // Get a list of the fields
            var fields = Object.keys(schema.properties);

            // Set some properties on all fields.
            fields.forEach(function(field) {
                schema.properties[field].required = false;
                schema.properties[field].nullable = true;
            });

            // Create the model.
            ds.createModel(tablename,
                schema.properties,
                {
                    plural: tablename,
                    core: true,
                    base: "PersistedModel",
                    idInjection: false
                }
            )

            // Get an instance of the model.
            let model = ds.getModel(tablename);

            // Make the model public with a REST API.
            app.model(model, { dataSource: dataSourceName, public: true });

        // Error
        } else {
             ....
        }

        // Return
        ........

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I've actually been able to create models that work on top of MySQL views, and they have functioned exactly as you described, and it's been pretty awesome. My question is - is it possible to create the view such that it ONLY exists in Loopback, and doesn't have an actual view in MySQL behind it. Does that make sense?

Comment: You could use Loopback models relations. Or, you could just hardcode the SQL or pull the SQL from a database and execute it from within Node initiated from a Loopback end-point. https://strongloop.com/strongblog/defining-and-mapping-data-relations-with-loopback-connected-models/

Comment: Another option is to use something like knex.js. It allows you to code the SQL in a database independent manner resulting in a dynamically generated 'view' of sorts.

Comment: Knex.js looks interesting, thanks for the referral. I'll check that out. I've been really impressed with Loopback thus far, and was hoping that it had some integrated capabilities on this front.